# Python Variable with Asterisk

Tags: python

I need to create a variable with an asterisk.

```
originalFilePath = "/home/user/reports/file_name_xxxx.pdf"
```

The file_name will be replaced every day with a numeric value, like - file_name_20221116.pdf. How can I pass "*" - star, in the variable?

So the code would look like this -

```
originalFilePath = "/home/user/reports/file_name_*.pdf"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create like this,

```
originalFilePath = "/home/user/reports/file_name_xxxx.pdf"
```

You have to pass your arguments like the following way.

```
abc = "xxxx"  #abc is a variable name
originalFilePath = f"/home/user/reports/file_name_{abc}.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a variable with an asterisk.

I don't think you do.

What you seems to need is to get a list of files by a UNIX-style globbing pattern, so it's a job for [glob — Unix style pathname pattern expansion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module from stdlib.

```
import glob

report_pattern = "/home/user/reports/file_name_*.pdf"
reports = glob.glob(report_pattern)
# reports == ['/home/user/reports/file_name_20221116.pdf']
```